# How to find precision and recall of segmented image?

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I have tried this [code](https://github.com/nicjac/PHANTAST-MATLAB/blob/master/GUI/OptimizationTool/compareBinaryImages.m):

```
function [Fvalue,precision,recall,accuracy,JaccardIndex,TP,FP,TN,FN,FPrate,TPrate,MCC] = compareBinaryImages( reference, toTest )
%COMPAREBINARYIMAGES Compute various similarity metrics between two binary images
%   reference = grouth truth binary image
%   toTest = binary image to be compared to the reference image

if(ndims(reference)~=2 && ndims(toTest)~=2) 
    error('Inputs must be two 2-dimensional matrices'); 
end; 

%  TP = numel(find(reference==1 & toTest==1)==1); % True positive
%  FP = numel(find(reference==0 & toTest==1)==1); % False positive
%  TN = numel(find(reference==0 & toTest==0)==1); % True negative
%  FN = numel(find(reference==1 & toTest==0)==1); % False negative


 TP = nnz(reference==1 & toTest==1); % True positive
 FP = nnz(reference==0 & toTest==1); % False positive
 TN = nnz(reference==0 & toTest==0); % True negative
 FN = nnz(reference==1 & toTest==0); % False negative

P = TP + FN; % Total positive for the true class (= reference)
N = FP + TN; % TOtal negative for the true class (= reference)

FPrate = FP/N; % False positive rate
TPrate = TP/P; % True positive rate

precision = TP/(TP+FP);
recall = TP/P;
accuracy = (TP+TN)/(P+N);

MCC = (TP*TN-FP*FN)/sqrt((TP+FP)*(TP+FN)*(TN+FP)*(TN+FN));
2/((1/precision)+(1/recall));

% Alternative form for Fvalue
2*(precision*recall/(precision+recall));

% Avoid getting a division by 0 if only negatives and perfect detection
if(TN==numel(reference))
    'gaga'
    Fvalue = 1;
    warning('FValue was set to 1 as all pixels were true negatives');
else
    Fvalue=2*TP/(FP+TP+P);
end

2*TP/((FP+TP)+(TP+FN));

JaccardIndex = TP / (FP+TP+FN);

end
```

My testing image is [image]

My reference image is [image]

But I got the result as NaN. What's wrong with this?

Comment: What results are NaNs? There are multiple outputs from the function in the link. Have you tried to debug the code?

Comment: yes.i used rgb2gray(reference) and rgb2gray(toTest) and then compareBinaryImages( reference, toTest )

ans =

   NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the attached function, `compareBinaryImages`, expects **binary** inputs, i.e., input images which contain only 0's and 1's. binarize your images and apply this function to the binary images results in several numeric outputs, non of which is Nan:

```
testingImg = imread('testing.png');
referenceImg = imread('reference.png');
% grayscale
testingGray = rgb2gray(testingImg);
referenceGray = rgb2gray(referenceImg);
% binarize
testingBw = testingGray == 255;
referenceBw = referenceGray == 255;
% compare *binary* images
[Fvalue,precision,recall,accuracy,JaccardIndex,TP,FP,TN,FN,FPrate,TPrate,MCC] = ...
    compareBinaryImages(referenceBw, testingBw);
```

Comment: but why large values? TP =

        7117


FP =

        1990


TN =

      368716


FN =

        2866

Comment: you should go through the definitions of these values and you will understand. `TP` (true positive) for example, is the **number of pixels** which are 1 both in the test and in the reference image.

Comment: @user3217708, you should understand that the TP, FP, TN and FN can be calculated at both pixel level (like you do) or at blob level (considering a segmented blob). At the blob level, you need extra criteria to define those values for e.g. a blob can be considered as TP when it overlaps the ground truth blob by a certain %.  This is common in medical imaging when working with 3D volumes.